# Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The signed app works fine but as soon as I upload the app to play store, the firebase phone authentication throws  Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode? error.

Comment: Just needed to get the keys from google play after signing app for production in the developer console

Comment: Yes it works for me

Comment: @Carlos Murray  See answer.Go to the Project Setting>Integration>Google Play. Link your Google Play account to firebase from which you have created your Firebase account and Google Play Console.It will work for me. It will also worked for you also. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution much easier to do.. All you need to do is link your Firebase account to your google Play console, you can do this from firebase console.
Project settings->Account linking->Google Play. Hope it works for you.

By doing this it will add/register all your app signing certificates SHA1 to firebase

Comment: It is compulsory to make payment to create account on Google Play console for link app google play?

Comment: yes you will have to pay in order to have a google play account to serve your apps on play store

Comment: I found it in Project settings->integrations (tab)->Google Play (card), then click "link".
Thanks @CarlosMurray - you saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to add a new SHA1 code on Firebase?
If you try to build the project on other computer or you re-install your OS, you may face this problem.
In those cases, you can create a new SHA certificate fingerprint and add it to the settings of your firebase project.
I hope it would help you.