# Firebase Authentication Returning 400

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get familiar with Firebase for an Android app. For testing purposes I'm just using a blank activity that attempts to create a user when the app starts up which I'm launching in the android emulator on OSX.

Activity is just this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("name@gmail.com", "random_string");
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

This appears to launch in the emulator just fine, but my Firebase user dashboard shows no changes. I have enabled the email and password flow for user signup.

The only hint is this:

```
2018-11-27 16:03:43.930 18564-18829/? E/Volley: [1569] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?alt=proto&key=key_string_was_here
```

I don't see any logging information on the Firebase side so I'm really not sure what's going wrong. Does anyone have any suggestions on where to start digging?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424223/unexpected-response-code-400-for-https-www-googleapis-com-identitytoolkit-v3-r

Comment: Thanks. I think the console has changed as the linking is no longer an option. Also, I had to provide the SHA1 fingerprint when I set up the project in firebase. These are instructions I followed when setting up: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Comment: ugh. I'm dumb. I wasn't including the ".com" in the email string. There was a message about this further down the logs, but it was marked severity info not error so I kept missing it.

Answer (score 3):

ENABLE the type of authentication(Email and Password, phone number..) you are using in the app from Firebase Console under the authentication tab

Answer (score 1):

I'm development phase. I got the same error when tried to register new user while I was signed-in as another one.

Just try

```
signOut();
```

before registration to confirm. Or better - redesign the app to not allow it for signed-in users.

Answer (score 0):

```
After uploading app to Play Console, you'll get Signing Keys:
Follow:
Goto Play Console: Select App -> Menu -> Release Dashboard ->  App Signing
and copy App Signing SHA-1 
and goto 
Firebase  -> Project Settings and Search for Add Figerprint:
Add fingerprint: then paste the key there. That's it

Note: Remember to remove SHA-1 from key else it will spit error fingerprint format not matching and make sure you have enabled authetication from firebase.
```

It will work 100%