# app works perfectly fine on the emulator but when running on my device it doesn't login/register

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I don't have much information to provide as I have no idea what the problem is. It works just fine when I run it on the emulator but when I try to run it on my device I can't get past the login/register. This is my login code, pretty straight forward and the register is pretty much the same so I won't bother to post it:

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        login_button.setOnClickListener {

            performLogin()

        }

    }


    fun backToRegistration (view : View) {
        val registerIntent = Intent (this, RegisterActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(registerIntent)
    }

    private fun performLogin(){

        val logEmail = login_email.text.toString()
        val logPass = login_password.text.toString()

        Log.d("Main", "email is $logEmail")
        Log.d("Main", "pass is $logPass")

//        Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(logEmail).matches()  <--- this method was used before for the if statement but I've replaced it as I kept getting the invalid email error for some reason.

        if (logEmail.contains("@") && logEmail.contains(".")) {

            if (logPass.length > 5) {

                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(logEmail, logPass).addOnCompleteListener {
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        Log.d("Login", "Successfully logged a user in using uid: ${it.result?.user?.uid}")
                        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        return@addOnCompleteListener
                    }
                    //else if successful
                    Log.d("Login", "Failed to log in a user")

                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.d("Main", "Failed to create user : ${it.message}")
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Your password needs to be at least 6 characters long", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid email address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }


}
```

This is my logcat (level set to error) right after I attempt a login:

```
2019-03-12 17:23:56.496 730-17078/? E/voice: voice_is_in_call:in_call 0
2019-03-12 17:23:56.496 730-17078/? E/voice: voice_is_in_call:in_call 0
2019-03-12 17:23:56.496 730-17078/? E/voice: voice_is_in_call:in_call 0
2019-03-12 17:23:56.497 730-17078/? E/msm8974_platform: platform_check_backends_match: Invalid snd_device = 
2019-03-12 17:23:56.497 730-17078/? E/soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_stream_status: invalid input device 0x0, for event 3
2019-03-12 17:23:57.290 3268-12575/? E/Volley: [2631] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyDVSMXQ9fymqlaJiaDogQt7i6-5j3xUbmY
2019-03-12 17:23:57.370 884-1070/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "sys.thermal.para"
2019-03-12 17:23:58.028 912-976/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-03-12 17:23:59.683 730-5610/? E/soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_stream_status: invalid input device 0x0, for event 2
2019-03-12 17:24:02.371 884-1070/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "sys.thermal.para"
2019-03-12 17:24:07.379 884-1070/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "sys.thermal.para"
2019-03-12 17:24:12.380 884-1070/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "sys.thermal.para"
```

Comment: None of those log messages look like they have anything to do with Firebase.

Comment: @DougStevenson I know, I have no idea what's wrong. If I run the app on the emulator I am able to login and create new users with no issues. I've tagged Firebsae becaue I use it for these operations and something isn't working. It's not necessarily related to Firebase but it might for all I know

Comment: `BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400`<- problem is here, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424223/unexpected-response-code-400-for-https-www-googleapis-com-identitytoolkit-v3-r) out.

Comment: @Swati thank you, that wasn't the solution completely but sent me n the right direction! The difference here was that my app is just running on my device and not actually on the app store. The solution was adding my SHA-256 to my Firebase project

Answer (score 2):

To anyone facing the same issue here are two possible solutions, based on your situation.

1. If your app is on the app store and you're having that issue, refer to the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424223/unexpected-response-code-400-for-https-www-googleapis-com-identitytoolkit-v3-r) Thank you @Swati for referring it to me.
2. If you are just trying to run it on your phone for testing and, make sure that you've provided the SHA certificate fingerprints in your Firebase project. If you're not sure what that means, go to your project settings -> General and SHA certificate fingerprints 
   should be under "Your apps".

You will need to enter both SHA-1 & SHA-256

To get them go to your Android project and click the "Gradle" tab on the almost-top right corner of the window (using windows, not sure about mac).

Then navigate to your project -> :app -> Tasks -> android and double click the "signingReport".

It should run some lines at the bottom of your window where your log cat is usually and in them you would find both SHA-1 and SHA-256